# How to update Redis list item?

Tags: redis

I'm currently researching high scalable web site architectures,nearly all of the articles i've read say that Redis is very good choice for a timeline(facebook,twitter like) architecture.So let's suppose that I'm building a new social network and I want to save last 500 feeds of each user with Redis,I'm just curious about what will happen when a user delete a feed which is in last 500 feeds? I couldn't find any information about updating Redis list item,if there is no such a thing in Redis how can it be a very good choice?

Comment: I'm unsure with regards to the "feeds" question, but Lists are very good for adding/removing from their ends and less so for updating an arbitrary item in them

Comment: @Ryan I'm not sure u've understood me.

Comment: sorry for any confusion caused by my misunderstanding.

Comment: f you want user 'a' to have list with a feed  'feed_1'  in it and user 'b' to have a list with 'feed_1' in it then the answer provided by @zodvik will do that. Be aware that the key 'feed_1' is unique. If you update the value associated with it then the new value will be changed everywhere.The 'list' hashes' etc hold 'references' to keys. [Use SET feed_1 <new value> to change the value associated with a key](http://redis.io/commands/SET),

Answer (score 2):

Using the Lset command will allow you to update a list item: https://redis.io/commands/lset

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a list, a better redis structure to use would be the [sorted set](http://redis.io/commands/#sorted_set), assuming you want to maintain ordering of the last 500 feeds.

To add new entry, you can use the command `ZADD user_id:feeds time_in_epoch feed_id`. The time_in_epoch would be score for sorting the set & will maintaining a ordering on the feeds.

To delete a feed for a user, `ZREM user_id:feeds feed_id`.

Comment: If ordering is not required, you can use a set instead of a sorted set.

Comment: add and delete ok but how can update a feed in the list?